# Convert type 'Map<string, string>' to type '{ [key: string]: string; }' in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript. I have a map in typescript like below:

```
const mapping = new Map<string, string>();
mapping.set('fruit', 'apple')
mapping.set('vegetable', 'onion')
...
```

I am trying to convert mapping to type '{ [key: string]: string; }'

How to do that in typescript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply do:

```
Object.fromEntries(mapping)
```

Reference:

- [`Object.fromEntries()` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

---

[Complete example:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA5IJZgOYwLwzAUwHcYBZZAHmgCd0MAaGa2gPgAoBKAKE8RVoDoI+KKwDkAMyoBXVFFENRyJABt8orrzSZBwsQDd8GYQgBGq+TFHhU4dd1CQQq-spAZWm2l04B6HzABvGABtAGt8AE8ALkYoGkwAXRimTBgAXxhUCEYEOHwYBGyAJXxQKgATSjjaBhSMZk4HaBgqUpAKmKCwyOTqxN74rAzcAHkTACtSqH5JEDgAUTBq-AgPJS97cAgnfBc3Vlay8q4gA)

```
const mapping = new Map<string, string>()

mapping.set('fruit', 'apple')
mapping.set('vegetable', 'onion')

console.log(mapping)

// { [key: string]: string } is same as Record<string, string>
const record: { [key: string]: string } = Object.fromEntries(mapping)

console.log(record)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define an empty object with the new mapping.

Use the Map [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) to iterate over the keys.

```
const mapping = new Map<string, string>();
mapping.set('fruit', 'apple')
mapping.set('vegetable', 'onion');
mapping.set('meat', 'chicken');
mapping.set('drink', 'beer');

console.log(mapping);

const newMapping : { [key : string] : string} = {};

mapping.forEach((val,key) => {
newMapping[key] = val;
});

console.log(newMapping);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA5IJZgOYwLwzAUwHcYBZZAHmgCd0MAaGa2gPgAoBKAbgFgAoRFLQB0EfFFYByAGZUArqigSGE5EgA2+Cez4C0mEWMkA3fBjEIARhqUwJ4VOC09+q4aPES4+BIuXAAFqjAANb4YE46rvrukgAmNGDBNhIW+PhUEbx8oJAgGkJqIBisurRcfNng0HhEZIKYMABcMADeMADaoQCeTYxQCRgAur1MmAC+OK1jzpH1GEJSIFQAoggBrKxGCGp03ew4zK18BIR1ehid+F3DuFtqzmPlWbw5EHn4BUWsJ2dlnEA)